# Center div inside absolute div

Tags: html, css

see this link...: [Exemple](http://www.alsite.com.br/novo/varcare/)

on this site i have this code

```
    <body>
    <div id="geral">
        <div id="animacao">
            <ul id="banners"> 
                <li><img src="banners/banner_1.jpg" alt="Banner 1" /></li>
                <li><img src="banners/banner_2.jpg" alt="Banner 2" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">

        </div>              
    </div>
</body>
```

`#geral` is positioned in the center of the screen -

`#animacao` has the same size of `#geral`, on this has animated images with fade effects..

`#menu` has 271px with and need to stay over and on center of `#geral` and `#animacao`, on this i will put the menu with PNG bakcground....

This is my CSS, and probably doesn't work ...

```
#geral{
    position: absolute;
    width:990px;
    height:530px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-265px;
    margin-left:-495px;
    background: url(../imagens/fundo.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#animacao{
    position: relative;
    width:990px;
    height:530px;
}

#menu
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width:271px;
    height:530px;
    margin-left:-135px;
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Where am I wrong?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qmAN5/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/C4jSS/

Or did you want the #menu div positioned on top of #animacao?

html

```
<div id="geral">
    <div id="animacao">
        <div id="menu">

        <div>
    </div>       
</div>
```

css

```
#geral{
    position: absolute;
    width:990px;
    height:530px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-265px;
    margin-left:-495px;
    background-color: black;
}

#animacao{
    position: relative;
    width:990px;
    height:530px;
    background-color: red;
}

#menu{
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:271px;
    height:530px;
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: the yellow div must be Over the red div... this will contain a transparent image with menu...

Comment: i have updated my question.. see the exemple i have make... but the "yellow" div isn't on the center....

Comment: I have updated my JSFiddle to show that. Looks like there's already a great answer posted above though.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `left: 50%` and add `margin: 0 auto;` to the `#menu` `div`.

```
#menu{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:271px;
    height:530px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qmAN5/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/qmAN5/2/show

Comment: the yellow div must be Over the red div... this will contain a transparent image with menu...

Comment: @Preston, please update your original question to better explain your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't exactly know what you are trying to ask but try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="geral">
<div id="animacao">fdgdf</div>
</div>
<div id="geral">   
<div id="menu">dfgdf     </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#geral{
    width:990px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    background: #99CCCC;
}

#animacao{

    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:530px;
    background:#FFCCCC;
}

#menu{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:271px;
    height:530px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    z-index: 10;
    border:#000000 1px solid;
    display:table;
}
```

Comment: like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/710/93922016.jpg/

but on the red, i have <ul> <li> images </li> </ul> for background transitions...

Comment: Do you have a list in the red area? Does the content of yellow area changes when you click the list item? Is that you are trying to say?

Comment: i have updated my question.. see this.. pls.... about your last question.. no.. the yello area receives the menu links.... and logo...only...

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/qmAN5/3/

I've put the #menu inside #animacao since the position is relative to its parent.
and added margin-left to adjust the position.

Comment: exactly so, but this way will be able to use a transition of images inside the #animation ? i will use like this:

Comment: why not? the problem here is that you must show exactly what you are trying to achieve, so we can give you a better answer.

Comment: i have updated my question.. see the exemple i have make... but the "yellow" div isn't on the center..and sorry for confusion...